# E: Unable to locate package with sudo apt install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

Whenever I do `sudo apt install` with some package name it is showing E: Unable to locate package .

I have removed 'install-info' file earlier. Does this causing the problem?
Also software center is showing no applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is mean the package is not on the distribution repository. If you want to install the package, you should add the repository manually by searching for a repository that contains the package you want.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to explain how (more or less) you find and add a repository?